# Spring Boot - MongoDB - MongoLab configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, mlab

I'm trying to configure my Spring Boot backend to connect to a MongoDB hosted on MongoLab.

The problem is it tries to connect to localhost. The error I get is:

```
2017-06-12 17:34:05.046  INFO 11843 --- [127.0.0.1:27017]
 org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I tried excluding MongoAutoConfiguration.class but I get the same error.

My code:

**FoodappBackendApplication.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
//@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FoodappBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FoodappBackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.port=8181
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver
spring.data.mongodb.database=foodapp
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<myusername>:<mypassword>@ds123456.mlab.com:12345/foodapp
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database: admin
```

**SpringMongoConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "foodapp";
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml dependencies:**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@Bean mongo()` from `SpringMongoConfig` and for that matter remove the class all together as you have already provided all the necessary configuration in the `application.properties` file.

Update your `FoodappBackendApplication` to

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FoodappBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FoodappBackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

For Java based configuration you can take a look at this.

[Spring Boot does not read MongoDB configuration from Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479348/2683814)

Comment: Thank you very much! I got confused there

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues I can see:

1. Is your intention to use .yml or .properties? Assuming you want to use .yml you should rename your properties file to application.yml
2. Your YML indentation is wrong. Your file should look like this:

   `spring:
     data:
       mongodb:
         uri:  # note the indentation level of this key`

   which Spring then converts to a property `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

Comment: My intention is to use .properties. I'm new to this so I'm still learning. I updated my queston to reflect what I have now. I still have the same problem though.
Thanks for your help.